# What pattern should I use with transformers?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, design-patterns, transformer-model

I have my transformer abstract class:

```
public abstract class Transformer<T, S> {

    public abstract S transform(T object);

    public abstract T revert(S object);

    public List<S> transformArray(Collection<T> iterable) {
        try {
            List<S> transformed = new ArrayList<S>();
            Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                T element = iterator.next();
                transformed.add(this.transform(element));
            }
            return transformed;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    public List<T> revertArray(Collection<S> iterable) {
        try {
            List<T> transformed = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterator<S> iterator = iterable.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                S element = iterator.next();
                transformed.add(this.revert(element));
            }
            return transformed;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And I want to have my DTOTransformer, which is like

```
public abstract class DTOTransformer<DTOREQ, OTHER, DTORES> {

    Transformer<DTOREQ, OTHER> forwardTransformer;
    Transformer<OTHER, DTORES> backwardTransformer;

    // Not overriding, since isn't and hasn't a transformer
    public OTHER transform(DTOREQ object) {
         return forwardTransformer.transform(object);
    }

    // Not overriding, since isn't and hasn't a transformer
    public DTORES revert(OTHER object) {
         return backwardTransformer.transform(object);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I have not actually any implementation for backwardTransformer and forwardTransformer's transform() method. What I want is that when I create a subclass from DTOTransformer, for an example, ClientDTOTransformer then I have to implement the transform and revert methods (which are not the same of the methods that Transformer's class offers since I have a "triangular" transformation).

I have already tried using the adapter pattern but I couldn't find the way to implement it.

Do you know how I could do this? Or if you know a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: There is nothing to implement in `DTOTransformer` as that class has no `abstract` methods. What you want is to declare a *constructor* for `DTOTransformer` which enforces that (non-`null`) instances for `forwardTransformer` and `backwardTransformer` are provided as arguments upon object construction. Btw, learning about [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) will make your code much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right. I am going to implement it like you  just said. Do you think that i am doing the arquitecture fine or you would do it differently?

Comment: I don’t know enough about your software to say whether the architecture fits in. Besides the exception handling, it looks reasonable so far.